# My Discord bot isn't responding to a command to pull data from timezonedb

Tags: python-requests, discord.py, timezonedb

So it can actually show the info I want it to in the terminal. But when I prompt it to send it as a discord message it appears to be attempting to send a blank message. It's probably something stupid, but thank you for looking. The language is Python.

```
import os
import discord
import requests
import json
import pprint

client = discord.Client()

def get_time():
  response = requests.get("http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=W9BJQ3QMGG69&format=json&by=position&lat=37.9838&lng=23.7275")
  return pprint.pprint(response.json())
  

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$petertest'):
        clock = get_time()
        await message.channel.send(clock)


client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: please read about [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) so you don't use on_message for commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the pprint module to **print** the data to the console itself. That is the issue there

Changing your code to simply return the data will fix the error.

```
return response.json()
```

If you want to send the formatted json data to discord, you can use `json.dumps`:

```
if message.content.startswith('test'):
    clock = get_time()
    clock = json.dumps(clock, indent=4)
    await message.channel.send(clock)
```